# Using plotlib to create a SVG fails with "invalid y_range"

Tags: rust

I am trying to count the letters in a message and export them to an image.

I've successfully created a `BTreeMap` with the letters and counted them. What I'm having trouble with is exporting them to an SVG with plotlib. I am open to using other libraries but I feel like my issue is with using the library more than the library itself.

Here's my code for the counter

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
plotlib = "0.4.0"
```

**main.rs**

```rust
use std::collections::btree_map::BTreeMap;

use plotlib::style::BarChart;

fn main() {
    let message: &str = "This is a long message";
    let mut count = BTreeMap::new();

    for c in message.trim().to_lowercase().chars() {
        if c.is_alphabetic() {
            *count.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1
        }
    }

    println!("Number of occurences per character");
    for (ch, count) in &count {
        println!("{:?}: {}", ch, count);
        let count = *count as f64;
        plotlib::barchart::BarChart::new(count).label(ch.to_string());
    }
    let v = plotlib::view::CategoricalView::new();   
    plotlib::page::Page::single(&v)
        .save("barchart.svg")
        .expect("saving svg");
}
```

I expected this program to produce an SVG with the data in it, but thread main panics

```
Number of occurences per character
'a': 2
'e': 2
'g': 2
'h': 1
'i': 2
'l': 1
'm': 1
'n': 1
'o': 1
's': 4
't': 1
thread 'main' panicked at 'saving svg: ErrorMessage { msg: "invalid y_range: Range { lower: inf, upper: -inf }" }', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Comment: Please make sure to update the *title* of your post when updating the content.

Answer (score 1):

Your *view* is empty. Therefore, there is nothing to plot and the boundaries for the SVG are in their initial invalid state.

You have to add the `BarChart` to your `CategoricalView` and **then** use that view on a page, for example:

```
let mut data = Vec::new();

for (ch, count) in &count {
    println!("{:?}: {}", ch, count);
    let count = *count as f64;
    data.push(plotlib::barchart::BarChart::new(count).label(ch.to_string()));
}

// Add data to the view
let v = data
    .iter()
    .fold(plotlib::view::CategoricalView::new(), |view, datum| {
        view.add(datum)
    });

plotlib::page::Page::single(&v)
    .save("barchart.svg")
    .expect("saving svg");
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!